# OnChange event not working in Input Type = Number when click on spinner in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an

`<input type="number" class="post-purchase-amount"/>`.

I am calling an
ajax call when the value get changed. It is working (with the following code) when the cursor is in the
text box itself and doing any changes. But it not working when i click the spinner (up/down button) of the input type.

```
parentPanel.on("change", ".post-purchase-amount", null, function (event) {
    updateAmount($(this));
});
```

My problem is that i could use the "input" event here but that can call the ajax 
every time when in change the value like if i want to send value 65
then it calls twice when typing each number. I need to call ajax only when the value has been changed not every key
stroke.
Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance

Comment: use blur instead of change and then add on click functions to the other input up and down icons

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a function to throttle the input and trigger it on keypress instead. Something like this:

```
function throttle(func, interval) {
    var last = 0;
    return function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (last + interval < now) {
            last = now;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}


parentPanel.on("keypress", ".post-purchase-amount", null, throttle(function(event) {
    updateAmount($(this));
}, 800));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are watching for a change and anytime you make a change this is going to fire. What you could do instead is use focusout to watch when you "exit" the number input. What the below function does is it checks to see if the previous value is equal to the new value when you exit focus on the input. If the current value is not the same then it has been updated.

```js
var prevVal = $('.numOfPeople').val();

$('.numOfPeople').on('focusout', null, function(e) {
  var curVal = $('.numOfPeople').val();
  if(prevVal !== curVal) {
      //Value is different so do your updates here. 
      preVal = curVal;
      $('#changed').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numOfPeople" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">


<p id="changed" style="display: none;">Value has changed</p>
```